# keeping value encoding when submitting a form

Tags: php, forms, post

I am POSTing a form input with value:

http://www.domain.com/script.php?var1=1120&var2=254949&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain2.com%2Ffile%2Bname%3Fvar1%3Dvalue1

on the server (PHP) I get this value:

http://www.domain.com/script.php?var1=1120&var2=254949&url=http://www.domain2.com/file+name?var1=value1

is there anyway to receive the original un-decoded value?

Comment: Why do you want it encoded? Just encode it again.

Comment: @Rizier123 if I encode it it will encode the whole string and I will get: http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fscript.php%3Fvar1%3D1120%26var2%3D254949%26url%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain2.com%2Ffile%2Bname%3Fvar1%3Dvalue1

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode only part of your string. In order to achieve that, use function explode to make array of two elements, encode the second one and put them again together. Something like could be helpful.

```
$str ='http://www.domain.com/script.php?var1=1120&var2=254949&url=http://www.domain2.com/file+name?var1=value1';
$url = explode('url=',$str);
$str2 = $url[0].'url='.urlencode($url[1]);
echo($str2);
```

Comment: the "url" variable  is just an example it can be anything, so this solution will not work. I'm really looking for a way to get the POSTed value as-is, without any manipulation on my side